# NightwatchJS xpath only returning first element

Tags: javascript, xpath, nightwatch.js

I try to find and extract all encounters of Strings or prices that contain the € sign. My current code is always returning only the first encounter even though there are at least 7 more.

```
"//*[contains(text(), '€')]["+i+"]"

"//*[text()[contains(., '€')]]["+ i + "]"
```

That also only returns an encounter for the first node for both tries.

Comment: Show relevant portion of your HTML

Comment: Show your loop, too.